# How can I force LaTeX to do a break line using the pgfplots package?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I´m using `pgfplots` and `tikz` package to do some 3D graphs of some random functions, but it takes to much time to my computer to compile the tex file, so I want to create each groups of graphs in a separete document using the `standalone` documentclass and then import them using the `\includegraphic` command. The problem is that when I do this, all the graphs stay in the same line so they do not fit on the page. Here is what I have done:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[view={-40}{30}, baseline,
   zlabel=$Q^H_i$,
   xlabel=$P_i^H$, ylabel=$P_i^C$
]
\addplot3[surf,
   domain=4.5:18.5,
   domain y=9.5:25.5
]{exp(1)*x^(-.34)*y^(1.46)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
%---------------------------------
\hskip 3pt
%---------------------------------
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\begin{axis}[view={130}{30}, baseline,
   zlabel=$Q^H_i$,
   xlabel=$P_i^H$, ylabel=$P_i^C$
]
\addplot3[surf,
   domain=4.5:18.5,
   domain y=9.5:25.5
]{exp(1)*x^(-.34)*y^(1.46)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
%---------------------------------
\hskip 3pt
%---------------------------------
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\begin{axis}[view={230}{30}, baseline,
   zlabel=$Q^H_i$,
   xlabel=$P_i^H$, ylabel=$P_i^C$
]
\addplot3[surf,
   domain=4.5:18.5,
   domain y=9.5:25.5
]{exp(1)*x^(-.34)*y^(1.46)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Using the last code I´m getting this:

[image]

But I want something similar to what I get when I compile the same code in the main tex file (look that LaTeX do the alignment automatically), but as I said before it takes to much time and it is better to have the graphs previously done and then just import them (please ignore the dots in this last image):

[image]

Comment: Have you checked out tikz's externalize feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can let LaTeX do the alignment if you separate each of them into a separate `standalone` file:

[image]

### Notes

- The output you show is *not* the output that you get if you replace the `standalone` class with `article` in that the last image is *not* centered.
- The output does `not` fit within the standard margins. You can see this is you uncomment the `use package{show frame}`.
- If you use the following you will get each plot on its own line:

  ```
  \noindent\sloppy
  \includegraphics{GraphA}
  \includegraphics{GraphB}
  \includegraphics{GraphC}
  ```
- [The `filecontents` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/filecontents)
  was used to set up a file to read for this test case. 
  It is not needed in you actual use case.

---

Alternatively, you can use the `varwidth` option for the `standalone` class with `\par` in between to achieve:

[image]

---

### Code: Separate `standalone` files

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{GraphA.tex}
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[view={-40}{30}, baseline,
   zlabel=$Q^H_i$,
   xlabel=$P_i^H$, ylabel=$P_i^C$
]
\addplot3[surf,
   domain=4.5:18.5,
   domain y=9.5:25.5
]{exp(1)*x^(-.34)*y^(1.46)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{GraphB.tex}
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\begin{axis}[view={130}{30}, baseline,
   zlabel=$Q^H_i$,
   xlabel=$P_i^H$, ylabel=$P_i^C$
]
\addplot3[surf,
   domain=4.5:18.5,
   domain y=9.5:25.5
]{exp(1)*x^(-.34)*y^(1.46)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{GraphC.tex}
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\begin{axis}[view={230}{30}, baseline,
   zlabel=$Q^H_i$,
   xlabel=$P_i^H$, ylabel=$P_i^C$
]
\addplot3[surf,
   domain=4.5:18.5,
   domain y=9.5:25.5
]{exp(1)*x^(-.34)*y^(1.46)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

%\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\includegraphics{GraphA}
\hskip 3pt
\includegraphics{GraphB}
\hskip 3pt
\includegraphics{GraphC}%
\end{document}
```

---

### Code: `[varwidth]` class option

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[view={-40}{30}, baseline,
   zlabel=$Q^H_i$,
   xlabel=$P_i^H$, ylabel=$P_i^C$
]
\addplot3[surf,
   domain=4.5:18.5,
   domain y=9.5:25.5
]{exp(1)*x^(-.34)*y^(1.46)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\par
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\begin{axis}[view={130}{30}, baseline,
   zlabel=$Q^H_i$,
   xlabel=$P_i^H$, ylabel=$P_i^C$
]
\addplot3[surf,
   domain=4.5:18.5,
   domain y=9.5:25.5
]{exp(1)*x^(-.34)*y^(1.46)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\par
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\begin{axis}[view={230}{30}, baseline,
   zlabel=$Q^H_i$,
   xlabel=$P_i^H$, ylabel=$P_i^C$
]
\addplot3[surf,
   domain=4.5:18.5,
   domain y=9.5:25.5
]{exp(1)*x^(-.34)*y^(1.46)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, I´ll be using the standalone documentclass for each graph option, it looks like the easiest way to do this for now, but I wonder if there is a command to simply indicate LaTeX to do a breakline.

Comment: @AlderMiguel: You can also use the `varwidth` option of the `standalone` class.  See updated answer.